# RShiny selectInput not filtering data for renderPlot correctly

Tags: r, shiny, output, shinydashboard

I am attempting to make an interactive dashboard that display's the given data on a histogram by grouping sales attainment into buckets. This histogram should adjust with the selected year, quarter, or month. The app itself runs and displays everything correctly, however when a new month/quarter/year is selected the visuals do not change. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have the following dataset:

```
    date <- c("5/13/2016","1/11/2017","9/6/2016","4/17/2018","4/9/2017","5/23/2016",
              "8/5/2017","4/10/2018","12/26/2018","1/11/2016")
    employee_id <- c('738138','521743','566295','183475','614729','758291','523776',
                     '533564','634953','493395')
    name <- c('Toby','Kelly','Pam','Jim','Michael','Angela','Oscar','Kevin','Dwight','Andy')
    sales <- c('77632','85213','45839','5582','58587','64183','6133','117923','16372','111553')
    participation <- c('NULL','Y','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','Y','NULL')
    held_quota <- c('Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y')
    attainment_bucket <- c('70-89%','100-200%','0-29%','70-89%','30-69%','0-29%','0-29%',
                           '200-300%','70-89%','0-29%')

    sample_data <- data.frame(date,employee_id,name,sales,participation,held_quota,attainment_bucket)
```

I tampered with the data a bit so that I could work with it more, however I felt like it is important to know the changes here for interpretability purposes.

```
#adding in month&year coulmns to help break down views

class(sample_data$date)

x <- as.Date(sample_data$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

sample_data$mo <- strftime(x, "%m")
sample_data$yr <- strftime(x, "%Y")
sample_data$qrt <- quarter(x, with_year = FALSE, fiscal_start = 01)

#changing column names for front end purposes.

colName1 <- c("January" = "01", 
              "February" = "02",
              "March" = "03",
              "April" = "04",
              "May" = "05",
              "June" = "06",
              "July" = "07",
              "August" = "08",
              "September" = "09",
              "October" = "10",
              "November" = "11",
              "December" = "12")

colName2 <- c("Quarter 1" = "1",
              "Quarter 2" = "2",
              "Quarter 3" = "3",
              "Quarter 4" = "4")

col_alias <- function(x) {switch(x,
                                 "01" = "January",
                                 "02" = "February",
                                 "03" = "March",
                                 "04" = "April",
                                 "05" = "May",
                                 "06" = "June",
                                 "07" = "July",
                                 "08" = "August",
                                 "09" = "September",
                                 "10" = "October",
                                 "11" = "November",
                                 "12" = "December")}

col_alias2 <- function(x) {switch(x,
                                  "1" = "Quarter 1",
                                  "2" = "Quarter 2",
                                  "3" = "Quarter 3",
                                  "4" = "Quarter 4")}


#subsetting data to display sales reps that hold a quota 

newdata <- sample_data[grepl("Y", sample_data$held_quota),]

#fixing participation column into categorical for donut chart
newdata$participation[is.na(newdata$participation)] <- 0
newdata$participation <- factor(newdata$participation, labels = 
                                  c("0-99%","100%")) 

#grouping data
newdata2 <- newdata %>%
  group_by(yr, mo, qrt) 

buckets <- newdata2$attainment_bucket
```

UI portion starts here:

```
ui = dashboardPage( skin = "blue",
                    dashboardHeader( title = "Sales Breakdown "), 
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        radioButtons("yearOption", "Select Year:", choices = 
                                       c("2016", "2017", "2018")),
                        radioButtons("timeView", "Select View:", choices = 
                                       c("Monthly", "Quarterly", "YTD")),
                        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.timeView == "Quarterly"',
                                         selectInput("quarter1", "Quarter 1", choices = 
                                                       colName2),
                                         selectInput("quarter2", "Quarter 2:", choices = 
                                                       colName2)),
                        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.timeView == "Monthly"',
                                         selectInput("month1", "Month 1:", choices = colName1),
                                         selectInput("month2", "Month 2:", choices = colName1)),
                        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.timeView == "YTD"'),
                        numericInput('n',
                                     "Number of Obervations",
                                     min = 1,
                                     max = 20,
                                     value = 5)
                      )

                    ),
                    dashboardBody(
                      fluidRow(
                        box(width = 6, plotOutput("hist1")),
                        box(width = 6, plotlyOutput("donut1")),
                        box(width = 12,tableOutput("table1"))

                      )
                    ))
```

Server portion starts here:

```
server = function(input, output) {

  output$hist1 <- renderPlot({


    g1 <-  ggplot(data = filter(newdata2, yr == input$yearOption & mo == input$month1
                                & qrt == input$quarter1)
                  , aes_string(x = 'buckets'))+ 
      geom_histogram(fill = "red", color = "black", stat = "count")+
      scale_x_discrete(limits=c("0-29%","30-69%","70-89%","90-99%",
                                "100%-200%","200-300%",">300%"))+
      theme_bw()

    if (input$timeView == 'Monthly') {
      return(g1 + labs(x="Attainment Buckets", 
                       title = paste(col_alias(input$month1), 
                                     input$yearOption)))
    }
    if (input$timeView == 'Quarterly') {
      return (g1 + labs(x="Attainment Buckets", 
                        title = paste(col_alias2(input$quarter1), 
                                      input$yearOption)))
    }
    else{
      return(g1 + labs(x="Attainment Buckets", 
                       title = paste("YTD",input$yearOption)))
    }

  })

  output$donut1 <- renderPlotly ({

    p <-  newdata2 %>%
      group_by(participation) %>%
      summarize(count = n()) %>%
      plot_ly(labels = ~participation, values = ~count) %>%
      add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
      layout(title = "Participation",  showlegend = T,
             xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, 
                          showticklabels = FALSE),
             yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, 
                          showticklabels = FALSE))
    print(p)

  })


  output$table1 <- renderTable ({

    head(newdata2[,2:7], input$n)

  })


}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the variable `buckets` try specifying the column that sits in your dataframe:

```
g1 <-  ggplot(data = filter(newdata2, yr == input$yearOption & mo == input$month1
                            & qrt == input$quarter1),
              aes(x = attainment_bucket)) + ## CHANGE THIS
  geom_histogram(fill = "red", color = "black", stat = "count") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("0-29%","30-69%","70-89%","90-99%",
                            "100%-200%","200-300%",">300%")) +
  theme_bw()
```

**EDIT:**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

date <- c("5/13/2016","1/11/2017","9/6/2016","4/17/2018","4/9/2017","5/23/2016",
          "8/5/2017","4/10/2018","12/26/2018","1/11/2016") employee_id <- c('738138','521743','566295','183475','614729','758291','523776',
                 '533564','634953','493395') name <- c('Toby','Kelly','Pam','Jim','Michael','Angela','Oscar','Kevin','Dwight','Andy') sales <- c('77632','85213','45839','5582','58587','64183','6133','117923','16372','111553') participation <- c('NULL','Y','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','Y','NULL') held_quota <- c('Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y') attainment_bucket <- c('70-89%','100-200%','0-29%','70-89%','30-69%','0-29%','0-29%',
                       '200-300%','70-89%','0-29%')

sample_data <- data.frame(date,employee_id,name,sales,participation,held_quota,attainment_bucket)

#adding in month&year coulmns to help break down views

class(sample_data$date)

x <- as.Date(sample_data$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

sample_data$mo <- strftime(x, "%m") sample_data$yr <- strftime(x, "%Y") sample_data$qrt <- quarter(x, with_year = FALSE, fiscal_start = 01)

#changing column names for front end purposes.

colName1 <- c("January" = "01", 
              "February" = "02",
              "March" = "03",
              "April" = "04",
              "May" = "05",
              "June" = "06",
              "July" = "07",
              "August" = "08",
              "September" = "09",
              "October" = "10",
              "November" = "11",
              "December" = "12")

colName2 <- c("Quarter 1" = "1",
              "Quarter 2" = "2",
              "Quarter 3" = "3",
              "Quarter 4" = "4")

col_alias <- function(x) {switch(x,
                                 "01" = "January",
                                 "02" = "February",
                                 "03" = "March",
                                 "04" = "April",
                                 "05" = "May",
                                 "06" = "June",
                                 "07" = "July",
                                 "08" = "August",
                                 "09" = "September",
                                 "10" = "October",
                                 "11" = "November",
                                 "12" = "December")}

col_alias2 <- function(x) {switch(x,
                                  "1" = "Quarter 1",
                                  "2" = "Quarter 2",
                                  "3" = "Quarter 3",
                                  "4" = "Quarter 4")}


#subsetting data to display sales reps that hold a quota 

newdata <- sample_data[grepl("Y", sample_data$held_quota),]

#fixing participation column into categorical for donut chart newdata$participation[is.na(newdata$participation)] <- 0 newdata$participation <- factor(newdata$participation, labels = 
                                  c("0-99%","100%")) 

#grouping data newdata2 <- newdata %>%   group_by(yr, mo, qrt) 

buckets <- newdata2$attainment_bucket

ui = dashboardPage( skin = "blue",
                    dashboardHeader( title = "Sales Breakdown "), 
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        radioButtons("yearOption", "Select Year:", choices = 
                                       c("2016", "2017", "2018")),
                        radioButtons("timeView", "Select View:", choices = 
                                       c("Monthly", "Quarterly", "YTD")),
                        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.timeView == "Quarterly"',
                                         selectInput("quarter1", "Quarter 1", choices = 
                                                       colName2),
                                         selectInput("quarter2", "Quarter 2:", choices = 
                                                       colName2)),
                        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.timeView == "Monthly"',
                                         selectInput("month1", "Month 1:", choices = colName1),
                                         selectInput("month2", "Month 2:", choices = colName1)),
                        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.timeView == "YTD"'),
                        numericInput('n',
                                     "Number of Obervations",
                                     min = 1,
                                     max = 20,
                                     value = 5)
                      )

                    ),
                    dashboardBody(
                      fluidRow(
                        box(width = 6, plotOutput("hist1")),
                        box(width = 6, plotlyOutput("donut1")),
                        box(width = 12,tableOutput("table1"))

                      )
                    ))

server = function(input, output) {
     output$hist1 <- renderPlot({


    g1 <-  ggplot(data = filter(newdata2, yr == input$yearOption & mo == input$month1
                                & qrt == input$quarter1),
                  aes(x = attainment_bucket))+ 
      geom_histogram(fill = "red", color = "black", stat = "count")+
      scale_x_discrete(limits=c("0-29%","30-69%","70-89%","90-99%",
                                "100%-200%","200-300%",">300%"))+
      theme_bw()

    if (input$timeView == 'Monthly') {
      return(g1 + labs(x="Attainment Buckets", 
                       title = paste(col_alias(input$month1), 
                                     input$yearOption)))
    }
    if (input$timeView == 'Quarterly') {
      return (g1 + labs(x="Attainment Buckets", 
                        title = paste(col_alias2(input$quarter1), 
                                      input$yearOption)))
    }
    else{
      return(g1 + labs(x="Attainment Buckets", 
                       title = paste("YTD",input$yearOption)))
    }
       })
     output$donut1 <- renderPlotly ({

    p <-  newdata2 %>%
      group_by(participation) %>%
      summarize(count = n()) %>%
      plot_ly(labels = ~participation, values = ~count) %>%
      add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
      layout(title = "Participation",  showlegend = T,
             xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, 
                          showticklabels = FALSE),
             yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, 
                          showticklabels = FALSE))
    print(p)
       })

     output$table1 <- renderTable ({

    head(newdata2[,2:7], input$n)
       })
      }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: When i specify the column "attainment_bucket" I get the following error "<text>:1:17: unexpected ';'
1: 70-89%; 100-200%;" , however I do not see where the semicolon is coming from.

Comment: That's weird, I can't seem to reproduce that. Try running my edit above

Comment: I got it to work, thank you! I was applying too many filters on the data for the ggplot, so I had to split it up into if/else statement.